# Algorithm to sanitize MySQL data

Tags: php, mysql, algorithm, codeigniter

Let's say I have a table of 100,000 MySQL records in a table with 2 columns: title and description.
There's also a table containing all the bad words that need to be sanitized.

For e.g. let's say the title column contains the string "Forget this" and the profanity table says that the "Forget" string should be replaced with "F*****".

Currently I implemented it with a brute force method, but this is way too slow. It checks every single substring from the sentence and compares it with every single string that exists in the profanity filter.

```
public function sanitizeSiteProfanity($word, $replacement)
{
    $query = $this->_ci->db->select('title, description')->get('top_sites')->result_array();
    $n = $query->num_rows();
    for($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++)
    {
        str_replace($word, $replacement, $query[$i]['title']);
        str_replace($word, $replacement, $query[$i]['description']);
    }   
}
```

Is there a faster method to sanitize all the substrings?

Comment: strtr() will be much faster

Comment: Can you show sample data from `bad words` table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if there is a fast way to sanitize the data.  It seems that you have to loop through all the words for the replacement, because one title could have multiple offensive words.

If you are looking for complete words, a full text index and contains should speed things up.  Essentially, you would set up a loop for each of the words and then run:

```
update table
    set title = replace(title, 'F***')
    where match (title) against ('Fuck' in boolean mode);
```

You would need to put this in a stored procedure loop.  But, the `match()` would be quite fast and this would probably significantly speed up the current process.

Comment: Is it possible to generate this using CodeIgniter's active record class?

Comment: Sanitizing in db will be much faster. There will be no data transfer overhead.

Comment: The results are fast enough. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

The best way to optimize this is to delegate the replacement step to the database and let mysql do the heavy lifting. You'll need to use the `REPLACE` mysql built-in. The (not-so-big) drawback is that you'll need to use explicit sql instead of the code igniter expression builder.

Comment: The sanitization needs to be done directly from the website and I need the user wait time to be as low as possible.

Comment: This *will* be faster than doing the replacement in a php loop.
Also - what does 'needs to be done directly from the website' mean?

Comment: @kjanko If you're required to do this on the php side exclusively, and can not do explicit sql queries, than please note that in the original question.